# how to paginate with an array of file names read from a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have an array of file names that are read from my public/images/pj_pics/ directory. The array has thousands of images, and I want to have the page display a max of 100 pics per page.

I've looked at the will_paginate gem, but it seems to only be designed for data from models (https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki)

Here's how I read the file names into @f_ary:

```
class AvatarsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = "pixelated avatars"
    @f_ary = Dir.entries("public/images/pj_pics/")
    @f_ary.delete(".")
    @f_ary.delete("..")
    @f_ary = @f_ary.each_slice(25).to_a
  end
end
```

I display the images in a big table like this:

```
%table
  %tbody
    - @f_ary.each do |row|
      %tr
        - row.each do |column|
          %td= link_to image_tag("pj_pics/#{column}", :alt => 'img')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like:

```
in_groups_of(per_page)[page-1]
```

Don't need to bother with will_paginate for paginating straight forward arrays.

Also, instead of using Dir#entries, you could use a glob, that way you can specify the extensions of the files that you want to use WITHOUT removing "." and ".."

Comment: Well, you need to think of your problem is being an Array, not a possible ActiveRecord collection. Which bit in particular is confusing, the glob bit or the array methods?